# Splitting polylines in ramps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, contour, line, splitting

I have a shapefile (polylines) of some roads and I want to divide the roads in ramps.

Ramp = a piece of the road delimited by the top of a hill and a valley.

So, pretending that you're driving in these roads, when you're going up you have one polyline for this part of the path, when you start going down you have another polyline of this path.

I have the **Digital Elevation Model** of the area, which I made using the "Topo to Raster" tool from "Spatial Analyst". To make it I used the shapefile of the rivers (stream), the limit (boundary), the point elevation and the contour (10 meters)

---

I found a set of tools called **ET Surface** and what I need is exactly what the tool  **"Split PolylineZ based on slope direction change"** does, but I don't have the licence to use it.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

1. Run the [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) tool to intersect your roads with your contours with the output type set to POINT.
2. Run the [Split Line At Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Split_Line_At_Point/00170000003w000000/) tool to cut up your road network? This tool requires you to have the Advance (Arcinfo) license.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this is the way but I still have some problems... I created the multipoint feature using the intersect like you said, but, when I used the split line at point, it didn't cut the roads every point intersection. I didn't unsderstand the sense of the cuts.

Comment: I've tryed the Split Line at Point tool again and it worked, I put a radius of 20 meters.