# Split 3D line feature at vertices based on slope change

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, line, 3d-analyst, slope

I've already asked [Splitting polylines in ramps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71081) about this subject, but now I think I'm almost getting to the point.

I have to split roads in ramps to calculate LS factor (RUSLE - soil erosion)

These are the steps that I'm trying to do:

1. Create a DEM using Topo to Raster
2. Convert the roads (polyline features) to 3D features using Interpolate shape (ArcGIS 10.1)
3. Split line at vertices.

but now the problem begins...

There are too many vertices in each polyline.

Is there a way to "clean" these vertices leaving only the ones where the slope abruptly changes (from going up to going down) or maybe create points at the Z min and Z max?